# Compressing a large number of files

Tags: compression, zip

I know that compressing files reduces the size of the files, sometimes at the expense of quality, so I was wondering how to compress a selection of files whose total size is larger than the maximum amount allowed when a .zip compression method is used. If the maximum filesize for compressing using the .zip method is 4GB, what can I do to compress files with a total size greater than 4GB?

Comment: *sometimes at the expense of quality* it depends. For image you can apply compression with loss, as it is the case with JPEG. For generic compression (zip, gzip, etc.) it is certainly loss**less** because you sure would like to recover the same thing before compression and after decompression.

Answer (score 3):

You're confusing two different types of compression.

**Lossy compression** is that used to shrink media files, such as pictures, audio, and video. MP3 and JPG compress audio and images by removing some of the data. Once you have converted a file to one of these lossy formats there is no way to get that file back to its original form and quality.

Lossy compression is usually a function of the media package (.mp3, .jpg, mp4) and of the encoding (the "code" method the media is stored as).

**Lossless compression** packages files of all types by using algorithms and other techniques, typically minimizing or de-duplicating duplicate and repeat data. Zip, 7zip, and RAR are common lossless compression forms. Files packaged in these formats CAN be returned to their full original size without any loss of data.

Mixing these types of compression does not usually result in further space savings. Pictures, audio, and video do not often package smaller when placed in zip files.

The 4GB limit is in the original zip specification. The only way around this would be to break the files into smaller chunks. However, there are alternatives to zip that do not have this limitation, and specific implementations of zip may have gotten past this limitation, though you may find a larger file created by one zip program may not be able to be extracted by a different zip program.

Finally, the file system you're storing the files on will need to support large enough file sizes too.

So, to answer your question: **find the right tool for the job**.

- [**RAR** supports a maximum file size of **8,589,934,591GB**](https://www.win-rar.com/faq.html?&L=0#c1427)
- [**7zip** supports maximum file sizes of **16,000,000,000GB**](https://www.7-zip.org/7z.html)

Use one of these. (hint: Use 7zip. It's free and is considered one of the best compression utilities and formats, period).

Comment: Both these numbers are from the official sites/FAQs for the respective apps and are in the suggested answer when you Google the question "x maximum file size".